# Time is not shown in mode line

Tags: mode-line

```
    Given:
Home:
    Laptop Lenovo Legion 
    OS: Linux Mint 21
    Emacs 27.1

Office:
PC
   OS: Linux Mint 21
   3 Displays
   Emacs 29.1
```

In init.el I set time in mode line like this:

```
(display-time-mode 1)
```

And time successfully show in the mode line:

[image]

OK.

In the office's machine I use the **same** Emacs's settings.
But time doesn't show in the mode line:

[image]

Run `emacs-Q`
on office's machine and

```
M-x display-time-mode
```

[image]

On home's laptop run `emacs-Q` and

```
M-x display-time-mode
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, `display-time-mode` without any settings (i.e., from `emacs -Q`) does not show the date, though. Can you try `M-x display-time-mode` from both machines with `emacs -Q` and see if the results are the same? If so, I suggest bisecting your configuration.

Comment: @ManuelUberti the OP might have `display-time-day-and-date` set to `t`: that's probably why he gets the date and you (and I) don't.

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that the settings are nor the same between the two computers. It may be that the the init files are different or it may be that the office computer finds a different init file than the one you think is applicable. Doing as @ManuelUberti suggested, `M-x display-time-mode` on the office computer should toggle the time display on (and off if you do it again). If that works, then check *which* init file you are using, with `C-h v user-init-file`; if it is different than the one you *think* you are using, then move it aside and try again.

Comment: @ManuelUberti I was updated my post

Comment: So `display-time-mode` is already enabled on the office computer when you start it with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @NickD No. I was updated my post

Comment: Well, when you start from `emacs -Q` you are getting the same results on both computers, right? Then I'd suggest following NickD instructions and make sure you are in fact using the same settings. Either that, or you can bisect your configuration as I suggested in the first place.

Comment: @ManuelUberti I checked, and I use the same init.el

Comment: @ManuelUberti I removed Emacs 27.1 and install Emacs 29.1 and time is not visible.